# Expected chromatic number

Tags: probability, graph-theory

If $ G = (V, E) $ is an undirected graph where each edge is included with probability $ p \in [0,1] $ is there a way to calculate $\mathbb E[\chi (G)]$ using elementary methods? Or at least establish some non-trivial bounds?

Comment: Although this is not precisely your question, the martingale inequality of Azuma can be used that $\chi(G)$ is close to $\mathbb{E}[\chi(G)]$ most of the time.